# How to reduce time taken on threads reaching Safepoint - Sync state

Tags: jvm, jit, async-profiler

About the Issue:
During heavy IO in the VM, we faced JVM pause/slowness due to stopping threads taking more time. When looking on safepoint logs it showed Sync state takes the most time.

[image: Safepoint log reference]

We also tried printing Safepoint traces on timeout delay (-XX:+SafepointTimeout -XX:SafepointTimeoutDelay=200) to know which threads is causing this issue but nothing seems to be suspicious. Also when setting timeout for safepoints, we are not getting timeout detected print when the time spent is in 'Sync' state.

*Questions about this safepoint tracing:*

1. How does the safepoint timeout work?
2. After logging the thread details, does the safepoint exists and all threads resume?
3. Will that VM operation be carried out. What will happen if the vmop is GC.

Using Async-profiler:
Tried time-to-safepoint profiling using async-profiler and noticed VM Thread is taking more time on SafepointSynchronize::begin() method and C2 compiler threads is taking almost equal time as VM Thread.

[image: Flame Graph]

*We doubt that C2 Compilers may be taking time to reach safepoint. Can someone help us in resolving this issue and to interpret this time-to-safepoint flamegraph. Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 3):

`SafepointTimeout` option affects nothing but logging, i.e. threads will not be interrupted, VM operation will run normally, etc.

`SafepointTimeout` does not always print timed out threads: a thread may already have reached the safepoint by the time printing occurs. Furthermore, `SafepointTimeout` may not even detect a timeout, if the entire process has been frozen by the Operating System.

For example, such 'freezes' many happen

- when a process has exhausted its cpu quota in a cgroup (container);
- when a system is low on physical memory, and [direct reclaim](https://lwn.net/Articles/396561/) occurs;
- due to activity of another process (e.g. I observed long JVM pauses when `atop` utility inspected the system).

[async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/) indeed has a time-to-safepoint profiling option (`--ttsp`), though using it correctly may seem tricky. It works best in `wall` profiling mode with `jfr` output. In this configuration, async-profiler will sample all threads (both running and blocking) during safepoint synchronization, and record each individual event with a timestamp.

Such profile can be then analyzed with JDK Mission Control: choose the time interval around the long pause, and look at the stack traces of *java* threads in this interval.

Note that if the JVM process is 'frozen', async-profiler thread does not work either, i.e. you will not see collected samples during this period. Normally, in wall clock profiling mode, all threads are sampled evenly. But if you see a 'gap ' (missed events during some time interval), it apparently means the JVM process has not received CPU time. In this case, the reason of JVM pauses is not in the Java application, but rather in the operating system / environment.

Comment: Thanks @apangin we had tried wall profiling mode with jfr output and we can find only sleeping threads during the time interval and running threads are not found. This seems to be the frozen state case. Btw, there is no CPU shortage in our case and only the IOWait is present. This case happens whenever we make a disk write of certain size(like >1GB). Can you please share if there is any way to debug the frozen state? Is there any relation b/w IO and sync state?

Comment: @Arunkumar It's hard to tell without seeing the profile. But excessive I/O definitely can be a reason of pauses.