# How to print gc log rotating cost in openjdk11?

Tags: logging, jvm, jvm-arguments, openjdk-11

guys.
In my case, I guess gc log rotating cause a long pause safepoint almost 10s.And I find we can print gc log rotating cost in JDK8u242+ with UseGCLogFileRotation Flags:[https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8231398?jql=text%20~%20%22GC%20log%20rotation%22%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC%2C%20affectedVersion%20DESC](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8231398?jql=text%20%7E%20%22GC%20log%20rotation%22%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC%2C%20affectedVersion%20DESC)

But in openJDK11, the UseGCLogFileRotation flag had been removed, and I try logging=trace not to affect. How to print the details for log rotating cost in openJDK11 now (with xlog options)?

Answer (score 0):

As a part of [JEP 271](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/271) implementation, the log rotation was moved out of safepoints since JDK 9. So, it cannot be a direct reason of a long safepoint pause, and there is no more option to print GC log rotation times.

Seems like this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and your original issue is the long pauses rather than printing log ration costs.

[async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/) can help in finding the cause of long pauses. Run it in the wall-clock mode (`-e wall`) with `jfr` output. It also has time-to-safepoint profiling option (`--ttsp`) specifically for detecting reasons why it takes long for the JVM to reach a safepoint. See the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67232199/how-to-reduce-time-taken-on-threads-reaching-safepoint-sync-state).